# Section of a projective morphism

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X \to Y$ be a projective morphism. So, this map factors through a closed immersion $i$ of $X$ into $\mathbb{P}^n \times Y$ for some $n$ followed by the projection map to $Y$. When is it possible to define a map $\phi$ from $Y$ to $\mathbb{P}^n \times Y$ such that the image of $\phi$ is contained in the image of the closed immersion $i$ such that $\phi$ composed with the projection map is identity? When can we say that $\phi$ is itself a closed immersion.

Comment: Well, a trivial condition is that $dim(X)\geq dim(Y)$ and if equal then $X=Y$. I don't see any other very general conditions.

Comment: @IMeasy: This seems to a very general condition. Could you please elaborate or suggest some reference for your answer.

Comment: IMeasy: I guess you're saying that these are trivial necessary conditions, but I think the situation is a bit more subtle than you claim in the case of equal dimension. First of all, one could do something stupid like have X be two disjoint copies of Y. So maybe you want to restrict to X connected. But in that case, one could take Y to be Spec(k), and X to be Spec(k[t]/t^2). 

Comment: I do not think there are general conditions for existence of $\phi$. Do you have some particular case in mind? If $\phi$ exists, it is clearly a closed immersion, since it is the graph of a morphism $Y\to\mathbb{P}^n$.

Comment: Also, I agree with Mohan that the question is too broad to expect a reasonable answer. It would be better to ask about a particular case.

Comment: Yes I assumed a couple of reasonable hypothesis, like $X$ smooth, irreducible and reduced

Comment: @Mohan, Smith: We can assume that both $X$ and $Y$ are smooth. The example I have in mind is applying Chow's lemma to a proper morphism $Y' to Y$ which gives rise to $X$ as described in the question.